# I want to move all files from one folder to other folder using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I want to move all files from one folder to other folder using shell script.
This is my code but it throws error

```
    #!/bin/sh
    SRC = '/home/xxx/test1/'
    DESTN = '/home/xxx/test/'
    mv SRC DESTN

Error:./move.sh:2:./move.sh:SRC:not found
      ./move.sh:2:./move.sh:SRC:not found
      mv:cannot stat 'SRC': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

When declaring shell variables, you cannot add spaces between the variable name and the `=` sign, nor between the `=` and the value.

Also remember to add `$` before the variable name when using it after its declaration.

Your script should look like this one:

```
#!/bin/sh
SRC="/home/xxx/test1/*"
DESTN="/home/xxx/test"
mv "$SRC" "$DESTN"
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdullatif Eymash its working now :)

Comment: @rkta thank you for the hint. I edited the answer.